# Load assembly call method return custom type

Tags: c#, reflection, return-value, usertype

Hope somebody can help me here. Basically I have to load 2 Assemblies dynamically for example

```
ObjA= Assembly.LoadFrom(folder + module); //had the main methods of the integration
ObjB = Assembly.LoadFrom(folder + module_decl); //has more interface declarations for the intigration
```

Now `ObjB` has the return value declaration for a method in `objA`. Thus I first try and find this return value and create a Type of it for example

```
  Type intObj ;

   Type[] type2 = objB.GetTypes();

       foreach (Type t in type2)
            {
                if ((intObj == null) && (t.FullName == "IIReturnInterfaceDecl"))
                {

                    intObj = t;

                }
            }
```

And then I go and create a instance of the main class and call the method

```
foreach (Type t in types)
                {

                mi = t.GetMethod("CreateTheObjectMethod");

                if (mi != null)
                {
                    string typeName = t.FullName;
                    object lateBoundObj = null;
                    lateBoundObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);


                    intObj = lateBoundObj.GetType().InvokeMember("CreateTheObjectMethod",
                                                //BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                                                    null,
                                                        lateBoundObj,
                                                            args);


                    if (intObj == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("oops");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("done");
                    }
                    //
                   // break;

                }
                //result
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DAMMIT");
        }
```

But basically I cant get it to call the method and return the object the way I want, (the code above does not compile gives error

> *Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Type'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)")*

But I don't know how to get it to cast it to the correct type.

Note the external assemblies I load is 3rd party, I don't have headers or declarations for them I can access them but I don't have the interface or class declared for me to easily cast from, I must do it dynamically.

Will really appreciate any guidance. I have looked and searched a lot and saw a lot on 'Delegate' but the most I see is for making the calls and passing the values not for handling dynamic user type values being returned and using them.

Thanks for any help.

//EDITED : Had error in if statement, sorry about that for those that already responded, must have been : if (intObj == null) and not if (CreateTheObjectMethod == null)

This might help, this is basically the declaration for the Method I am calling

```
[System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo] = {IIReturnInterfaceDecl CreateTheObjectMethod(System.String, System.String)}
```

Comment: What line gives this error?

Comment: after you creating a instance of type why are you trying to get Type again? Same thing with method you are going to run.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - I get the error where I do the call " intObj = lateBoundObj.GetType().InvokeMember("CreateTheObjectMethod",
                                                //BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                                                    null,
                                                        lateBoundObj,
                                                            args);"

Comment: @Dilshod - was more playing around looking at the types (had a messagebox popuping up the type for me in the loops and in the case of the method I only went further with it when I found one that had the method in it.. thus more trail and error code at the end of day after becoming desperate..

Comment: @Soner Gönül - thanks for fixing my post, still very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this?

```
                mi = t.GetMethod("CreateTheObjectMethod");

                if (mi != null)
                {
                    string typeName = t.FullName;
                    object lateBoundObj = null;
                    lateBoundObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                    object returnValue = mi.Invoke(lateBoundObj,null);//pass your params instead of null if you need
                    //here you can check what return value is.
                    Type returnedType = returnValue.GetType();


                    if (CreateTheObjectMethod== null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("oops");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("done");
                    }
                    //
                   // break;

                }
```

Comment: no not really but will it automatically create a object of the method ? I will try. but dunno about this part "if (CreateTheObjectMethod== null)"

Comment: @Johannes I am not sure what exactly you want. What do you mean by "create a object of the method"?

Comment: Sorry I realised now that I pasted the wrong text in the if statement it must have been if (intObj == null) , not if (CreateTheObjectMethod == null), sorry about that, will see if there is way to edit original code, but basically I want to call the method "CreatObjectOfMethod" and I to use its return value. But I cannot cast to its return value type as the type is a usertype (class) that I dont have at compile time, only runtime. And if I only make the return value of type object I only get null back the whole time.

Comment: This might help, this is basically the declaration for the Method I am calling

    [System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo] = {IIReturnInterfaceDecl CreateTheObjectMethod(System.String, System.String)}

Comment: did you try the example I wrote? did you debug it? is it returning the object you want?

Comment: Yes I did, but it still returns null.Just so weird for the Methods description for the Reflection object does say that it returns the object that I want and on the main object I can see that it has successfully executed (as it sets certain properties there that tells me it has done so). Thus no error in execution, no exception but just no object back.. just null.

Comment: so if that method is returning null then we can't do anything except if we can see the code in that method.

Comment: thanks. I will keep on trying as I know it is returning something for it works when statically linked. If I get the answer, I will post it here. thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

`intObj` is of type `System.Type` and you are trying to assign the return value of `InvokeMember` to it. But the return value is `object`. That's what the error message is telling you.

You could simply cast the return value to `Type` but I doubt that this is correct. This would get rid of the compiler error but it would result in an exception at runtime if the return value of the invoked method (`CreateTheObjectMethod`) is not of type `Type`.
You need to assign the return value to a variable of the return type of `CreateTheObjectMethod` and cast the return value of `InvokeMember` accordingly.

Comment: this is what I try in the start when I create "intObj = t;" I do it for the Interface type (t.FullName == "IIReturnInterfaceDecl"). But then I am buggered, dont know how to force the Method call to return that type (cast the object return value).

Comment: @Johannes: You are confusing an instance of type `Type` and an instance of type `IIReturnInterfaceDecl`. In that case, `intObj` simply needs to be of type `object`, because I think the type `IIReturnInterfaceDecl` is not known at compile time.

Comment: that is what I thought, but if I do a normal call to it and make intObj of type object then it always returns null. that is why I started experimenting with this. But if I pull the Assemblies in to the IDE at design time then I can do these calls without error, but dynamically not. Unluckily I need them to be dynamically.

Comment: @Johannes: But the method returning `null` has nothing to do with the type the return value is assigned to... In your code you are checking `CreateTheObjectMethod` for `null` but you are assigning the return value to `intObj`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I just realize now that I have pasted that there instead of intObj, I was checking intObj for null, just changed the names for the post etc not to let out code.. will try and see if I can find way to edit orignal post, sorry about that.. but basically I check if intObj is null (if it got anything back or not). sorry

Comment: This might help, this is basically the declaration for the Method I am calling

    [System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo] = {IIReturnInterfaceDecl CreateTheObjectMethod(System.String, System.String)}